# AWS Lambda: Module initialization error with httplib2

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda

I have a problem with httplib2 not working in a Python Lambda function.

I have the following test case:

```
    import httplib2

    h = httplib2.Http()

    def handler(event=None, context=None):
        return 'ok'

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print handler()
```

httplib2 0.9.2 is deployed in the same directory as the test case code.

I get the following error on Lambda: module initialization error: 'module' object has no attribute 'Http'

Test case works as expected on local machine.

If I comment out the second line of code, it works on Lambda.

If I leave out the lib from the deployment bundle, import fails, so no other httplib2 is being used.

Any ideas what is happening here? This error is completely blocking my project.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem with another module. All libraries are present in zip package along with subdirectories and files. code works locally in a virtualenv with no packages installed. Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

When uploading code to AWS lambda ensure you have installed your dependencies to your local directory before creating a zipped file and uploading it. Typically  'module' object has no attribute 'Http' occurs when lambda cannot find your import. I would recommend you do the following inside your directory:

```
pip install httplib2==0.9.2 -t .
```

Your directory should look like the following if you run 'tree /f'

```
Your directory
│   simple_http_get.py
│
└───httplib2
    │   cacerts.txt
    │   iri2uri.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
            iri2uri.cpython-35.pyc
            __init__.cpython-35.pyc
```

For your python codebase (using simple-http-get.py), try the following. Note I've changed 'handler' to lambda_handler. This is the default entry point to your code - unless you have changed it.

```
import httplib2


def lambda_handler(event, content):
    """ entity point into lambda function """
    # GET request to google
    h = httplib2.Http()
    (response_headers, content) = h.request("http://www.google.com", "GET")

    # response_headers will contain the response code from the GET request
    response_code = None
    if response_headers.status == 200:
        return 'ok'
    else:
        return 'error'

    return response_code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ entry point for testing function locally """
    response_code = lambda_handler(event=None, content=None)
    print(response_code)
```

Comment: As stated, I have httplib2 in the same directory as the teat code, and if I remove it, I get an import error instead of the initialization error, which leads me to believe it is found. The directory trees match.

Comment: Can you confirm that your example above works on Lambda? Then I can concentrate on finding the problem in my Python install rather than the Lambda service. Thanks.

Comment: As the question says directory tree is not the problem.